# access current_page? in ApplicationJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

Do I have access to `current_page?` method in `ApplicationJob`?

I tried to use it and the job didn't work anymore.

```
def perform(message)   
  if current_page?(root_path)
    x = 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Jobs don't have pages, they're processed in the background completely decoupled from the request/response cycle.

Comment: Oh, that's true. So I need to pass the variale to the job and change it externaly, right?

Answer (score 1):

View/controller helpers are not available in ApplicationJob.

You have to pass it as argument:

```
def perform(message, path)   
  if path == Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_path
    x = 1
  end
end
```

P.S. I am not sure you really want to have performing a job be impacted by a controller path.